# Can MySQL convert a literal String to a expression?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

And that query returns the list of users

but now I have a stored procedure I call to return a new query string in the form of a varchar

```
"SELECT * FROM users where SomeCondition = true"
```

how can I tell MySQL to treat that varchar as a statement?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html maybe you should look into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by piotrgajow, you can use prepared statement.
[Documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM "SELECT * FROM users where SomeCondition = true";
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```